# My calculation for Givens rotation in a quantum state

Tags: rotations, quantum-mechanics

I am following a tutorial in Given rotations. Suppose I have the quantum state $|100\rangle$ and would like to use two Givens $G$ with angle $\theta, \phi$ rotation to transform it into a superposition of $\alpha|100\rangle+\beta|010\rangle+\gamma|001\rangle$. I denote $\cos(\frac\cdot 2), \sin(\frac\cdot 2)$ as $c(\cdot), s(\cdot)$

Consider $G(1,4,\phi)$ which maps $|100\rangle$ to $|001\rangle$
$$G(1,4,\phi)=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & c(\phi) & 0 & 0 & -s(\phi)& 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0\\
0 & s(\phi)& 0 &  0 & c(\phi) & 0& 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
and $G(2,4,\theta)$ which maps $|100\rangle$ to $|010\rangle$
$$G(2,4,\theta)=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & c(\theta)& 0 & -s(\theta)& 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0& 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & s(\theta)&  0 & c(\theta)& 0& 0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$G(2,4,\phi)G(1,2,\theta)$ is the mapping that I needs,
$$G:=G(2,4,\phi)G(1,4,\theta)=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&c(\phi)&0&0&-s(\phi)&0&0&0\\
0&-s(θ)s(\phi)&c(θ)&0&-cθs(\phi)&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&c(θ)s(\phi)&s(θ)&0&c(θ)c(\phi)&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Now $G|100\rangle=-s(\phi)|001\rangle-s(\phi) c(\theta)|010\rangle +c(\theta) c(\phi) |100\rangle$. However the supposed solution is $c(\theta)s(\phi)|001\rangle - s(\theta)|010\rangle + c(\theta)c(\phi)|100\rangle$. I don't understand how the 1st and 2nd coefficient is that way

Comment: First you set up $G(1,4,\phi)$ and $G(2,4,\theta)$, but then you use $G(2,4,\phi)$ and $G(1,2,\theta)$ – is that on purpose? Anyway, I suspect you'll get the desired answer if you swap the factors in the product.